# Ruby on Rails server crashes during a HTTPS POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to communicate with u[rban airship API](http://urbanairship.com/docs/push.html#broadcast) using a ROR web application.

In my controller I've the following code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'open-uri'

app_key = 'JJqrCewBT7e_...'
app_secret = 'lAu7MIeARCiacg_...'

payload ={
    "aps" => {"badge"  => "0", "alert" => "My push message", "sound" => ""}
}.to_json

full_path = 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/'
url = URI.parse(full_path)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.body = payload
req.basic_auth app_key, app_secret

con = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
con.use_ssl = true

con.start {|http| http.request(req)}
```

but when i call the controller's method my server crashes, throwing these errors (I know, it is not pleasant to see):

```
/Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby
1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]

-- control frame ---------- c:0074 p:---- s:0409 b:0409 l:000408 d:000408 CFUNC  :connect c:0073 p:0011 s:0406 b:0406 l:0022d0 d:000405 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678 c:0072 p:0031 s:0404 b:0404 l:000403 d:000403 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44 c:0071 p:0026 s:0392 b:0392 l:000391 d:000391 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87 c:0070 p:0444 s:0386 b:0386 l:0022d0 d:0022d0 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678 c:0069 p:0011 s:0378 b:0378 l:000377 d:000377 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637 c:0068 p:0048 s:0375 b:0375 l:000374 d:000374 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626 c:0067 p:0278 s:0372 b:0372 l:000371 d:000371 METHOD /Users/abramo/village/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:73 c:0066 p:0012 s:0362 b:0362 l:000361 d:000361 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4 c:0065 p:0015 s:0357 b:0357 l:000356 d:000356 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150 c:0064 p:0041 s:0352 b:0352 l:000351 d:000351 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11 c:0063 p:0012 s:0348 b:0348 l:001b98 d:000347 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18 c:0062 p:0123 s:0346 b:0346 l:000345 d:000345 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445 c:0061 p:0113 s:0340 b:0340 l:000339 d:000339 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409 c:0060 p:0024 s:0331 b:0331 l:000330 d:000330 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93 c:0059 p:0015 s:0325 b:0325 l:001b98 d:001b98 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17 c:0058 p:0012 s:0320 b:0320 l:000301 d:000319 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30 c:0057 p:0017 s:0316 b:0316 l:000306 d:000315 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52 c:0056 p:0032 s:0314 b:0314 l:000313 d:000313 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21 c:0055 p:0036 s:0307 b:0307 l:000306 d:000306 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52 c:0054 p:0152 s:0302 b:0302 l:000301 d:000301 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29 c:0053 p:0012 s:0296 b:0296 l:000295 d:000295 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17 c:0052 p:0093 s:0291 b:0291 l:000290 d:000290 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119 c:0051 p:0084 s:0285 b:0285 l:000284 d:000284 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41 c:0050 p:0048 s:0280 b:0280 l:000279 d:000279 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138 c:0049 p:0086 s:0275 b:0275 l:000274 d:000274 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14 c:0048 p:0030 s:0269 b:0269 l:001fc8 d:000268 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178 c:0047 p:---- s:0266 b:0266 l:000265 d:000265 FINISH c:0046 p:---- s:0264 b:0264 l:000263 d:000263 CFUNC  :call c:0045 p:0022 s:0260 b:0260 l:000259 d:000259 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62 c:0044 p:0094 s:0254 b:0254 l:000253 d:000253 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27 c:0043 p:0097 s:0248 b:0248 l:000220 d:000247 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148 c:0042 p:0014 s:0242 b:0242 l:000226 d:000241 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93 c:0041 p:0283 s:0237 b:0237 l:000236 d:000236 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75 c:0040 p:0198 s:0227 b:0227 l:000226 d:000226 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92 c:0039 p:0092 s:0221 b:0221 l:000220 d:000220 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139 c:0038 p:0025 s:0215 b:0215 l:000214 d:000214 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492 c:0037 p:0106 s:0211 b:0211 l:000210 d:000210 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.2/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54 c:0036 p:0015 s:0207 b:0207 l:000206 d:000206 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17 c:0035 p:0093 s:0200 b:0200 l:000199 d:000199 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14 c:0034 p:0155 s:0193 b:0193 l:000192 d:000192 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24 c:0033 p:0046 s:0187 b:0187 l:000186 d:000186 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21 c:0032 p:0054 s:0182 b:0182 l:000181 d:000181 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182 c:0031 p:0027 s:0175 b:0175 l:000174 d:000174 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149 c:0030 p:0015 s:0164 b:0164 l:000163 d:000163 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302 c:0029 p:0014 s:0156 b:0156 l:001650 d:000155 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32 c:0028 p:0019 s:0154 b:0154 l:000153 d:000153 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:2 c:0027 p:0051 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12 c:0026 p:0019 s:0146 b:0146 l:001650 d:001650 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31 c:0025 p:0015 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool. c:0024 p:0029 s:0138 b:0138 l:0019c0 d:000137 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46 c:0023 p:0155 s:0136 b:0136 l:000135 d:000135 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415 c:0022 p:0011 s:0126 b:0126 l:0019c0 d:0019c0 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44 c:0021 p:0015 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107 c:0020 p:0049 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48 c:0019 p:0017 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47 c:0018 p:0027 s:0100 b:0100 l:000099 d:000099 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13 c:0017 p:0032 s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17 c:0016 p:0052 s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72 c:0015 p:0014 s:0083 b:0083 l:000077 d:000082 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11 c:0014 p:0019 s:0081 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 METHOD <internal:prelude>:10 c:0013 p:0054 s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11 c:0012 p:0193 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30 c:0011 p:0032 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:168 c:0010 p:0021 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77 c:0009 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 FINISH c:0008 p:0015 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14 c:0007 p:0015 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13 c:0006 p:0338 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52 c:0005 p:0257 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111 c:0004 p:0393 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70 c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:0012f8 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183 c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ---------------------------------------- /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call' <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sass-3.1.2/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `_run__665867706682760905__process_action__896478572660211325__callbacks' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action' /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action' /Users/abramo/village/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:73:in `send_push_notification' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect' /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE] You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome. For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap
```

**Please, can you help me to understand what am I doing wrong?**

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also provide the C level backtrace?

Comment: It is completely blank... :-(

Comment: It gives me: "ruby: No such file or directory -- OpenSSL::SSL_VERSION (LoadError)"

Comment: Oops, my bad, it was late already :) I meant  ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION', sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!

There is a bug related to the 'pg' gem and the use of HTTPS connections.

The fix is trivial: just move the `gem 'pg'` line of your Gemfile to the bottom!

Comment: It's hard to imagine that this would work, but it just did for me.  Moved gem 'pg' to the bottom of the list in the Gemfile (but before where we usually declare group :development, group :test etc.). Re-ran bundle, started the server, and the segfaults stopped.