# Rails server shutting down - http.rb:678: bug segmentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

In my Rails 3 app I am attempting to load a User's tweets in a div container when I click a link. Sometimes when I do this I get a result. Other times my `rails server` shuts down and I get a huge error. What is going on?

Here is the controller action I'm attempting to load:

```
def profile_status
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @profile_tweets = Twitter.search("#pursuit from:#{@profile.twitter}")
end
```

If I run the following in `irb` it returns results so I have to assume that's not the issue:

```
$ irb
1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'twitter'
1.9.2-p290 :002 > Twitter.search("#hashtag from:username")
```

Here is what I get in my terminal shell window before the server shuts down:

```
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0089 p:---- s:0490 b:0490 l:000489 d:000489 CFUNC  :connect
c:0088 p:0011 s:0487 b:0487 l:0008b0 d:000486 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678
c:0087 p:0031 s:0485 b:0485 l:000484 d:000484 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44
c:0086 p:0026 s:0473 b:0473 l:000472 d:000472 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89
c:0085 p:0444 s:0467 b:0467 l:0008b0 d:0008b0 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678
c:0084 p:0011 s:0459 b:0459 l:000458 d:000458 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637
c:0083 p:0048 s:0456 b:0456 l:000455 d:000455 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626
c:0082 p:0025 s:0453 b:0453 l:000452 d:000452 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168
c:0081 p:0094 s:0446 b:0446 l:002010 d:002010 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:888
c:0080 p:0622 s:0438 b:0438 l:000437 d:000437 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:60
c:0079 p:0015 s:0427 b:0427 l:000426 d:000426 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/response.rb:8
c:0078 p:0015 s:0423 b:0423 l:000422 d:000422 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/response.rb:8
c:0077 p:0015 s:0419 b:0419 l:000418 d:000418 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/response.rb:8
c:0076 p:0027 s:0415 b:0415 l:000414 d:000414 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14
c:0075 p:0027 s:0411 b:0411 l:000410 d:000410 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:13
c:0074 p:0053 s:0407 b:0407 l:000406 d:000406 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter/request/multipart_with_file.rb:17
c:0073 p:0096 s:0403 b:0403 l:000402 d:000402 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/connection.rb:207
c:0072 p:0055 s:0394 b:0394 l:000393 d:000393 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/connection.rb:89
c:0071 p:0021 s:0388 b:0388 l:0025a0 d:0025a0 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter/request.rb:23
c:0070 p:0027 s:0380 b:0380 l:000379 d:000379 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter/request.rb:11
c:0069 p:0042 s:0374 b:0374 l:000373 d:000373 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter/client/search.rb:69
c:0068 p:0057 s:0369 b:0369 l:000368 d:000368 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter.rb:17
c:0067 p:---- s:0363 b:0363 l:000362 d:000362 FINISH
c:0066 p:0060 s:0361 b:0361 l:000360 d:000360 METHOD /Users/User/Desktop/myapp/app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:145
c:0065 p:0012 s:0358 b:0358 l:000357 d:000357 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
c:0064 p:0015 s:0353 b:0353 l:000352 d:000352 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150
c:0063 p:0041 s:0348 b:0348 l:000347 d:000347 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11
c:0062 p:0012 s:0344 b:0344 l:001828 d:000343 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18
c:0061 p:0093 s:0342 b:0342 l:000341 d:000341 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440
c:0060 p:0113 s:0336 b:0336 l:000335 d:000335 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409
c:0059 p:0024 s:0327 b:0327 l:000326 d:000326 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93
c:0058 p:0015 s:0321 b:0321 l:001828 d:001828 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
c:0057 p:0012 s:0316 b:0316 l:000297 d:000315 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
c:0056 p:0017 s:0312 b:0312 l:000302 d:000311 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52
c:0055 p:0032 s:0310 b:0310 l:000309 d:000309 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
c:0054 p:0036 s:0303 b:0303 l:000302 d:000302 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52
c:0053 p:0152 s:0298 b:0298 l:000297 d:000297 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29
c:0052 p:0012 s:0292 b:0292 l:000291 d:000291 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17
c:0051 p:0093 s:0287 b:0287 l:000286 d:000286 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119
c:0050 p:0084 s:0281 b:0281 l:000280 d:000280 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41
c:0049 p:0048 s:0276 b:0276 l:000275 d:000275 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138
c:0048 p:0086 s:0271 b:0271 l:000270 d:000270 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14
c:0047 p:0030 s:0265 b:0265 l:0011a8 d:000264 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178
c:0046 p:---- s:0262 b:0262 l:000261 d:000261 FINISH
c:0045 p:---- s:0260 b:0260 l:000259 d:000259 CFUNC  :call
c:0044 p:0022 s:0256 b:0256 l:000255 d:000255 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62
c:0043 p:0094 s:0250 b:0250 l:000249 d:000249 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27
c:0042 p:0097 s:0244 b:0244 l:000216 d:000243 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148
c:0041 p:0014 s:0238 b:0238 l:000222 d:000237 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93
c:0040 p:1562 s:0233 b:0233 l:000232 d:000232 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:124
c:0039 p:0198 s:0223 b:0223 l:000222 d:000222 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92
c:0038 p:0092 s:0217 b:0217 l:000216 d:000216 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139
c:0037 p:0025 s:0211 b:0211 l:000210 d:000210 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492
c:0036 p:0015 s:0207 b:0207 l:000206 d:000206 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17
c:0035 p:0093 s:0200 b:0200 l:000199 d:000199 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
c:0034 p:0155 s:0193 b:0193 l:000192 d:000192 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24
c:0033 p:0046 s:0187 b:0187 l:000186 d:000186 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
c:0032 p:0054 s:0182 b:0182 l:000181 d:000181 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182
c:0031 p:0027 s:0175 b:0175 l:000174 d:000174 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149
c:0030 p:0015 s:0164 b:0164 l:000163 d:000163 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302
c:0029 p:0014 s:0156 b:0156 l:001e00 d:000155 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32
c:0028 p:0019 s:0154 b:0154 l:000153 d:000153 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:2
c:0027 p:0051 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12
c:0026 p:0019 s:0146 b:0146 l:001e00 d:001e00 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31
c:0025 p:0015 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.
c:0024 p:0029 s:0138 b:0138 l:000f80 d:000137 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46
c:0023 p:0155 s:0136 b:0136 l:000135 d:000135 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415
c:0022 p:0011 s:0126 b:0126 l:000f80 d:000f80 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44
c:0021 p:0015 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106
c:0020 p:0049 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48
c:0019 p:0017 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47
c:0018 p:0027 s:0100 b:0100 l:000099 d:000099 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13
c:0017 p:0032 s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
c:0016 p:0052 s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
c:0015 p:0014 s:0083 b:0083 l:000077 d:000082 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
c:0014 p:0019 s:0081 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 METHOD <internal:prelude>:10
c:0013 p:0054 s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
c:0012 p:0193 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30
c:0011 p:0032 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:168
c:0010 p:0021 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77
c:0009 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 FINISH
c:0008 p:0015 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0007 p:0015 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13
c:0006 p:0338 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52
c:0005 p:0257 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111
c:0004 p:0393 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70
c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:0026c8 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:124:in `optimized_each'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `_run__16612505638329100__process_action__2901805260493971917__callbacks'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/User/Desktop/myapp/app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:145:in `profile_tweets'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter.rb:17:in `method_missing'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter/client/search.rb:69:in `search'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter/request.rb:11:in `get'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter/request.rb:23:in `request'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/connection.rb:89:in `get'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/connection.rb:207:in `run_request'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/twitter/request/multipart_with_file.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:60:in `call'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:888:in `get'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in another SO question here: [Ruby on Rails server crashes during a HTTPS POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628292/ruby-on-rails-server-crashes-during-a-https-post-request)

After moving `gem 'pg'` to the bottom it works!