# Ruby on Rails crash during request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use windows, ruby 2.5, rails 5.1.7, I have a controller with get request, from Unirest or RestClient libs. When I trigger it, the RoR server closes, I see windows error about ruby.
The same request command processed in rails console fine.

That theme was not helped [Ruby on Rails server crashes during a HTTPS POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628292/ruby-on-rails-server-crashes-during-a-https-post-request)

**UPDATED**

Rubymine log error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Controller code:

```
u = RestClient.get('https://google.com/')
```

Comment: Please provide the error message that is displayed. It is also helpful if you share the relevant code.

Comment: error just for Ruby 2.5; 2.2 version works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows error 0xC0000005 is memory access violation, it means that something is wrong with binaries - most probable native gem extensions or ruby itself,

so try `bundle pristine` to reinstall gems and if that does not help - cleanup and reinstall ruby.

Comment: Yes, just it helped, ruby 2.6 from rubyinstaller, it seems as unexplained windows issue.